# How to know max specified memory in Oracle XE11g release 2?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is the max specified memory in Oracle XE11g release 2? I have read in Oracle documentation that the allowed max memory for database is 1GB RAM. Is that per database or per session? And if it is per database, then how can I modify it per session?

Comment: It's per instance (="database") as far as I know. And you can't have multiple instances with XE either. So it's per installation.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear about this. See [Oracle Database Licensing Information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC116)

> **Oracle Database Express Edition**  Oracle Database Express Edition
>   (Oracle Database XE) is an entry-level edition of Oracle Database that
>   is quick to download, simple to install and manage, and is free to
>   develop, deploy, and distribute. Oracle Database XE makes it easy to
>   upgrade to the other editions of Oracle without costly and complex
>   migrations. Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size machine
>   with any number of CPUs, stores up to 11 GB of user data, using up to
>   1 GB of memory, and using only one CPU on the host machine. Support is
>   provided by an online forum.

The 10g [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BEIEJGGF) shows explicitly: 1 installation, 1 instance on a machine. Compared to 10g in 11g you can use more userdata on disk.